# How are two rel= attributes treated in a link?

Tags: html, seo, rel

Given a link that looks like this (which I know is wrong):

```
<a href="http://www.something.com/" rel="foo" rel="nofollow">something</a>
```

How would this have to be treated according to html standards, and how do search engines (i.e. Google) actually treat it? Will it end up as "foo nofollow", "foo", or "nofollow"?

I was stumbling across this, because I noticed that in Google Chrome developer tools the element is shown like so ...

[image]

while some plugins I tested out where highlighting the link as *nofollow*.

Comment: Chrome ironically isn't great for this, it may even sometimes auto-close an missing `</li>` in my experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attribute-name-state):

> When the user agent leaves the attribute name state (and before
>   emitting the tag token, if appropriate), the complete attribute's name
>   must be compared to the other attributes on the same token; if there
>   is already an attribute on the token with the exact same name, then
>   this is a parse error and the new attribute must be removed from the
>   token.

So the second one will be dropped.